# How to parse SOAP XML in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I write this code

```
$Data=date("Y/m/d");
$UserName="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$StationCode="xxx";
$ConsignorAccount="xxx";
$soapclient = new SoapClient("http://api.skynetwwe.info/eComApiV1.svc?wsdl");
$param=array('UserName'=>$UserName, 'Password'=>$password, 'StationCode'=>$StationCode, 'ConsignorAccount'=>$ConsignorAccount);
$response =$soapclient->VerifyUserAccount($param);
echo '<br><br><br>';
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response));  
var_dump($response);
echo '<br><br><br>';
var_dump($array);
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

and it gives me this result

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["VerifyUserAccountResult"]=> string(336) "﻿SUC005LOGIN DETAILS HAVE BEEN VERIFIED SUCCESSSFULLY7f969968-14a3-4ea9-a728-d55c53503a5b" }

object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["VerifyUserAccountResult"]=> string(336) "﻿SUC005LOGIN DETAILS HAVE BEEN VERIFIED SUCCESSSFULLY7f969968-14a3-4ea9-a728-d55c53503a5b" }
```

but it should give me results like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<VerifyUserAccountResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<VerifyUserAccountResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<StatusCode>SUC005</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>LOGIN DETAILS HAVE BEEN DERIFIED SUCCESSSFULLY</StatusDescription>
<RequestID>15baac9e-ba4a-458d-953d-05443ddc33c0</RequestID>
</Response>]]>
</VerifyUserAccountResult>
</VerifyUserAccountResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

pleas i need to read the value of RequestID and StatusCode how i can do this

Comment: That is a weird return from a soap server. Looks like you'll need to parse the xml from `$response->VerifyUserAccountResult`, and then find it in `$xmlObject->Response->RequestID`.

Comment: please, can you explain by code because I am a new coder :)